# Mongodb aggregate lookup three collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

Learning MongoDB for the past two days and I am trying to aggregate three collections but unable to achieve it

Below are the three collection maintaining in the database

**t_credentials**

```
{
    "_id" : "619ca68b624c41e408348406",
    "title" : "Company ID"
}
```

**t_groups**

```
{
    "_id" : "61a253da88ca12a37218898d",
    "group_name" : "Gold"
}
```

**t_user_credentials**

```
{
    "_id" : "619ca88a624c41e408348424",
    "credential_id" : "619ca68b624c41e408348406",
    "group_id" : "61a253da88ca12a37218898d",
    "identifiers" : {
        "first_name" : "Lee",
        "middle_name" : "Min",
        "last_name" : "Ho"
    },
    "created_at" : "2021-12-01T17:20:49.000Z"
}
```

Here I am trying to achieve the output in the below format:

**Expected Output**

```
[{
    "_id" : "619ca88a624c41e408348424",
    "first_name" : ,
    "middle_name" : ,
    "last_name" : ,
    "credential" : {
        "_id:" : "619ca68b624c41e408348406",
        "title" : "Company ID"
    },
    "group" : {
        "_id" : "61a253da88ca12a37218898d",
        "group_name" : "Gold"
    },
    "created_at" : "2021-12-01T17:20:49.000Z"
}]
```

But, I am getting the fields only from t_user_credentials but not able to get like in the above format

**Query**

```
db.t_user_credentials.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
               from: "t_credentials",
               localField: "_id",
               foreignField: "credential_id",
               as: "credentials"
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path:'$credentials',
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                 from: "t_groups",
                 localField: "_id",
                 foreignField: "group_id",
                 as: "groups"
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$groups', 
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                last_name: "$identifiers.last_name",
                first_name: "$identifiers.first_name",
                middle_name: "$identifiers.middle_name",
                "credentials.title": 1,
                created_at: 1,
                group_id: 1
            }
        }
      ])
```

Can any one help me to solve this issue, it will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

This query uses `$replaceWith` to merge the `identifiers` sub-document into the `$$ROOT` document. We also use `$unset` to remove fields we are no longer interested in. Before all of that we make sure to unwind our `credential` and `group` fields.

You can [check out a live demo of this query here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_uKY3zG_PNS)

Consider the following:

#### Database

```
db={
  "t_credentials": [
    {
      "_id": "619ca68b624c41e408348406",
      "title": "Company ID"
    }
  ],
  "t_groups": [
    {
      "_id": "61a253da88ca12a37218898d",
      "group_name": "Gold"
    }
  ],
  "t_user_credentials": [
    {
      "_id": "619ca88a624c41e408348424",
      "credential_id": "619ca68b624c41e408348406",
      "group_id": "61a253da88ca12a37218898d",
      "identifiers": {
        "first_name": "Lee",
        "middle_name": "Min",
        "last_name": "Ho"
      },
      "created_at": "2021-12-01T17:20:49.000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Query

```
db.t_user_credentials.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "t_credentials",
      "localField": "credential_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "credential"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "t_groups",
      "localField": "group_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "group"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$group",
    
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$credential"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $mergeObjects: [
        "$$ROOT",
        "$identifiers"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "group_id",
      "credential_id",
      "identifiers"
    ]
  }
])
```

#### Result

```
[
  {
    "_id": "619ca88a624c41e408348424",
    "created_at": "2021-12-01T17:20:49.000Z",
    "credential": {
      "_id": "619ca68b624c41e408348406",
      "title": "Company ID"
    },
    "first_name": "Lee",
    "group": {
      "_id": "61a253da88ca12a37218898d",
      "group_name": "Gold"
    },
    "last_name": "Ho",
    "middle_name": "Min"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) But I got an empty array instead. Anyway I sent an email to you, kindly please read